# How to wrap it correclty with Gettext?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make hard-coded text translatable in WordPress theme.

This is the code:

```
<a class="btn advanced-search-btn btn-full-width" data-toggle="collapse" href="#advanced-search-filters">
    <i class="houzez-icon icon-cog mr-1"></i> <?php echo houzez_option ('srh_btn_adv', 'Advanced');?>
</a>
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
<a class="btn advanced-search-btn btn-full-width" data-toggle="collapse" href="#advanced-search-filters">
    <i class="houzez-icon icon-cog mr-1"></i> <?php _e houzez_option ('srh_btn_adv', 'Advanced', 'wpml_theme');?>
</a>
```

It gave me an error:Syntax error, unexpected T_String

I have tried to replace `_e` with `__e` and also tried `esc_html__` but it give me the same error!

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?php echo houzez_option ('srh_btn_adv', 'Advanced');?>
```

with

```
<?php _e(houzez_option ('srh_btn_adv', 'Advanced'));?>
```